# ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application. on ElasticBeanstalk

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

So, I am launching my app with Elasticbeanstalk and I am using Ruby on Rails for my app. However, when I ran the command "eb deploy {name}", it showed me the error

```
Creating application version archive "app-4f49-180904_151051".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% 
Done...
2018-09-04 07:12:09    INFO    Environment update is starting.      
2018-09-04 07:12:15    INFO    Deploying new version to instance(s).
2018-09-04 07:12:47    ERROR   [Instance: i-0ae9e24acc3308f6d] Command 
failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: 
(TRUNCATED)...c65750cc.js.gz
rake aborted!
Autoprefixer doesn’t support Node v4.6.0. Update it.
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
(See full trace by running task with --trace). 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/11_asset_compilation.sh 
failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console 
or EB CLI.
2018-09-04 07:12:47    INFO    Command execution completed on all 
instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
2018-09-04 07:12:47    ERROR   Unsuccessful command execution on 
instance id(s) 'i-0ae9e24acc3308f6d'. Aborting the operation.
2018-09-04 07:12:48    ERROR   Failed to deploy application.        

ERROR: ServiceError - Failed to deploy application.
```

However, I have check my gemfile, and did not see Autoprefix of any kind. I hope I am providing enough info, if not, please guide me in providing more details and finding an answer for this. Thank you in advance.

My gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.5.1'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.0'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby

# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use ActiveStorage variant
# gem 'mini_magick', '~> 4.8'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
gem 'devise'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'omniauth-google-oauth2'
gem 'twitter'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'carrierwave', '~> 1.0'
gem "mini_magick"
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem "recaptcha", require: "recaptcha/rails"
gem 'impressionist'
gem 'social-share-button'
gem 'fog-aws'

# include bootstrap
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.1.0'

#include fontawesome
gem 'font-awesome-rails'

#include jquery & jquery ujs
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 6.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'autosize'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'select2-rails'
```

Comment: are you using yarn or NPM?

Comment: Do you have `mini_racer` gem installed ?

Comment: Hi @Verty00, I am using npm 4.1.2

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I do not have minir_racer install, I believe and I have included my gemfile in the question for better clarification.

Comment: Can you un-comment `mini-racer`, `bundle`, `add to git` and try to `deploy` again ?

Comment: @kedarnagMukanahallipatna I am currently running the bundler with it, a bit slower (not sure why) but could you tell me the reason for installing the mini-racer gem?

Comment: It's an issue with ExecJS. There was an issue raised few days ago. Here [it](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer-rails/issues/140) is.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna Error with libv8 installation, and based on a bit of reading, the gems are not compatible with ruby 2.5.1?

Comment: Can you update your question with the `error(full trace)` ? btw which OS are you using ?

Comment: @kedarnagMukanahallipatna Can deploy now, not sure what happened but I comment back mini_racer and it's working. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Same issue–fixed it by uncommenting `mini-racer` worked for me, like @KedarnagMukanahallipatna suggested above.

**Change From**

```
# Gemfile

# gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
```

**Change To**

```
# Gemfile

gem 'mini_racer', platforms: :ruby
```